# Cloudify File Plugin "Operation not permitted" error

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloudify

I'm attempting to copy a file to a VM using the `cloudify.nodes.File` type, but am running into a permission error that I'm having trouble figuring out.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.cloudify.co/4.5.5/working_with/official_plugins/utilities/files/), I should be able to copy a file by using:

```
docker_yum_repo:
type: cloudify.nodes.File
properties:
  resource_config:
    resource_path: resources/docker.repo
    file_path: /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo
    owner: root:root
    mode: 644
```

The relevant portions of my blueprint are:

```
vm_0:
  type: cloudify.nodes.aws.ec2.Instances
  properties:
    client_config: *client_config
    agent_config:
      install_method: none
      user: ubuntu
    resource_config:
      kwargs:
        ImageId: { get_attribute: [ ami, aws_resource_id ] }
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        UserData: { get_input: install_script }
        KeyName: automation
  relationships:
    - type: cloudify.relationships.depends_on
      target: ami
    - type: cloudify.relationships.depends_on
      target: nic_0
...
file_0:
  type: cloudify.nodes.File
  properties:
    resource_config:
      resource_path: resources/config/file.conf
      file_path: /home/ubuntu/file.conf
      owner: root:root
      mode: 644
  relationships:
    - type: cloudify.relationships.contained_in
      target: vm_0
```

But, I keep receiving the error:

```
2019-02-20 15:36:59.128  CFY <sbin> 'install' workflow execution failed:   RuntimeError: Workflow failed: Task failed 'cloudify_files.tasks.create' ->   [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: './file.conf'
Execution of workflow install for deployment sbin failed. [error=Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/dispatch.py", line 571, in _remote_workflow_child_thread
workflow_result = self._execute_workflow_function()
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/dispatch.py", line 600, in _execute_workflow_function
result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/plugins/workflows.py", line 30, in install
node_instances=set(ctx.node_instances))
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/plugins/lifecycle.py", line 29, in install_node_instances
processor.install()
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/plugins/lifecycle.py", line 102, in install
graph.execute()
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/workflows/tasks_graph.py", line 237, in execute
raise self._error
RuntimeError: Workflow failed: Task failed 'cloudify_files.tasks.create' -> [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: './file.conf'
```

I've tried a few different values for `file_path`: "/home/ubuntu/file.conf", "/tmp/file.conf", and "./file.conf" (shown in the error output above), but I receive the same permission error each time. I've also tried the relationship: `cloudify.relationships.depends_on` without any success as well.

I'm using Cloudify Manager 4.5.5 via their Docker image.

Has anyone seen this issue? Am I using the plugin incorrectly? And is this "best-practice" or should I create a new VM that already has all of the files necessary and have that spun-up on AWS?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**
I forgot to mention that if I try to set the owner of the file to `ubuntu:ubuntu`, I get an error about the user not being found:

```
2019-02-20 16:19:21.743  CFY <sbin> 'install' workflow execution failed:     RuntimeError: Workflow failed: Task failed 'cloudify_files.tasks.create' -> 'getpwnam(): name not found: ubuntu'
Execution of workflow install for deployment sbin failed. [error=Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/dispatch.py", line 571, in _remote_workflow_child_thread
workflow_result = self._execute_workflow_function()
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/dispatch.py", line 600, in _execute_workflow_function
result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/plugins/workflows.py", line 30, in install
node_instances=set(ctx.node_instances))
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/plugins/lifecycle.py", line 29, in install_node_instances
processor.install()
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/plugins/lifecycle.py", line 102, in install
graph.execute()
  File "/opt/mgmtworker/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudify/workflows/tasks_graph.py", line 237, in execute
raise self._error
RuntimeError: Workflow failed: Task failed 'cloudify_files.tasks.create' -> 'getpwnam(): name not found: ubuntu'
```

It looks like the VM isn't yet ready to receive the file (since it's failing in the install lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

Try "use_sudo: true" in the "resource_config" block.  Also add an interfaces block like this:

    `interfaces:
      cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle:
        create:
          executor: host_agent
        delete:
          executor: host_agent`

If you don't override the executor, it will run on the manager (which is probably why you see "ubuntu" user not existing).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave that a try and get another error: `CFY <sbin> 'install' workflow execution failed: RuntimeError: Workflow failed: Task failed 'cloudify_files.tasks.create' -> Missing cloudify_agent.queue runtime information. This most likely means that the Compute node was never started successfully`. From quickly searching Google, it sounds like I may need to use Fabric to create a connection before the file can be transferred. Sound right? Also, the instance does start successfully, so I don't think the error message is accurate.

Comment: The only thing that's confusing me is that it seems like Fabric is used only to execute commands on the Compute (at least it seems that way from the documentation)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you weren't using agents.  Without agents, the "host_agent" executor config is meaningless.  Are you not able to use agents?

Comment: Ended up going with a different method since I was having trouble getting the agent installed (couldn't get fabric to work so running commands was out of the question). Now I'm using Ansible as a post-startup step to send files and do other things. I'll continue playing with the host_agent and fabric and attempting to get the file transfer to work. I'll post again if I succeed